# How to get Top 3 box aggregation in pandas groupby - percentage of scores greater than 7 in 10-point scale?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following **Input pandas dataframe**:

```
Index respID company    month  score
    0    101     AAA   Oct'18      8
    1    102     AAA   Oct'18     10
    2    103     AAA   Oct'18      5
    3    104     AAA   Oct'18      4
    4    105     BBB   Oct'18      5
    5    106     BBB   Oct'18      6
    6    107     BBB   Oct'18      8
    7    108     BBB   Oct'18      1
    8    109     AAA   Nov'18      5
    9    110     AAA   Nov'18     10
   10    111     AAA   Nov'18      4
   11    112     AAA   Nov'18      7
   12    113     AAA   Nov'18      8
   13    114     BBB   Nov'18      9
   14    115     BBB   Nov'18      2
   15    116     BBB   Nov'18      5
   16    117     BBB   Nov'18      1
```

I need to aggregate a big pandas dataframe with Top 3 box metric - percentage of occurrences of score 8,9,10 on a 10-point scale.

So, the aggregated **output pandas dataframe** should look like:

```
        Index   TOP3
(AAA, Oct'18)   0.50
(BBB, Oct'18)   0.25
(AAA, Nov'18)   0.40
(BBB, Nov'18)   0.25
```

I was told that is a very common metric in marketing, but I did not find any close aggregation. I tried several approaches like using:

```
AGGR=df.groupby(['month','company'])['score'].apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x)/x.count())
```

but then I would need to do another aggregation by score summaries and so on

Is there any good way to get Top 3 aggregation in one shot?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `mean`:

```
d = dict(ratio=df.score >= 8)

df.assign(**d).groupby(['company', 'month'])['ratio'].mean()
```

```
company  month
AAA      Nov'18    0.40
         Oct'18    0.50
BBB      Nov'18    0.25
         Oct'18    0.25
Name: ratio, dtype: float64
```

---

To find the top 2,3,4 using the same logic:

```
d = dict(
  top2=df.score >= 9,
  top3=df.score >= 8,
  top4=df.score >= 7
)

df.assign(**d).groupby(['company', 'month'])[[*d.keys()]].mean()
```

```
                top2  top3  top4
company month
AAA     Nov'18  0.20  0.40  0.60
        Oct'18  0.25  0.50  0.50
BBB     Nov'18  0.25  0.25  0.25
        Oct'18  0.00  0.25  0.25
```

Comment: Works well on my big 3.5 million records dataframe! Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to get Top2, Top3, Top4 in one assign statement ?

Comment: @Chris, Thank you very much!

Comment: @ibarant I generalized it a bit more.  Instead of having to specify `['top2'...etc]`, you can simple use `[[*d.keys()]]` to calculate based on all the values in your dictionary

Comment: @Chris, you made my day. Have a great weekend!

Comment: @Chris, in my big dataframe, you generalized code works only if it looks like:  df.assign(**d).groupby(['company', 'month'])[d.keys()].mean()      (without * and extra subsetting the dictionary. Is there a need to update the answer? I use python 2.7

Comment: Ah, in python 3 (which I use) you can't use that, since it isn't a list.  I'll leave it as it, and I would also recommend upgrading to Python 3 :)